# MARKDOWN Bold text

Tags: markdown, doxygen

i want to make a bold C++ like this:

some text here and **C++** and some text here..

"**C++**" was shown after generating PDF file.

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did a small test in one of my files, looks like a bug in doxygen, please file an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: A pull request has been made for this problem (although no issue was submitted!). Code has been integrated in master on github.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in doxygen:

- sequences in the form `**C++**` should look like **C++** but look like **C++**
- work around: use the HTML tags (works also for doxygen LaTeX output) `<b>` and `</b>`, so `<b>C++</b>` will look like **C++**

Edit:
In the current version 1.8.15 the version with the asterisks **C++** and the underscores __C++__ both result in bold text **C++** for the given example.

Comment: Quote: *"In the current version 1.8.15 the version with the asterisks **C++** and the underscores __C++__ both result in bold text C++ for the given example."* - I cannot confirm this for Doxygen version 1.9.8.

Comment: @ingo You wrote "I cannot confirm this for Doxygen version 1.9.8." is this a typo and should it read "I can confirm this for Doxygen version 1.9.8." or otherwise how does you example look like. When I run doxygen version 1.9.8 or the current doxygen version (1.10.0) I see that the `**`  and `__` texts are bold.

Comment: No typo, I meant can**not**, but trying to give an example I cannot reproduce my observe. Maybe I have seen some side effects with configuring Doxygen that has gone now? So forget it. You are right. Everything is working as expected now.